LLDB-17 Crashes with Floating Point Exception When Debugging LLVM-Based Compiler Project
I’m working on a compiler project based on LLVM and encountering an issue when trying to debug my unit tests using LLDB-17. The debugger crashes with a floating point exception both in VSCode and from the command line. Interestingly, LLDB-17 works fine with another project.
Here are the details of the crash:
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/ and include the crash backtrace.
 #0 0x00007f179a641406 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) (/usr/lib/llvm-17/bin/../lib/libLLVM-17.so.1+0xccc406)
 #1 0x00007f179a63f5b0 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/usr/lib/llvm-17/bin/../lib/libLLVM-17.so.1+0xcca5b0)
 #2 0x00007f179a641a9b (/usr/lib/llvm-17/bin/../lib/libLLVM-17.so.1+0xccca9b)
 #3 0x00007f1799459520 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x42520)
 #4 0x00007f17a5412ffa (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x7fdffa)
 #5 0x00007f17a5412ebe (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x7fdebe)
 #6 0x00007f17a5414a44 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x7ffa44)
 #7 0x00007f17a514db47 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x538b47)
 #8 0x00007f17994b0ee8 __pthread_once_slow ./nptl/pthread_once.c:118:7
 #9 0x00007f17a514bda7 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x536da7)
#10 0x00007f17a555ff43 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x94af43)
#11 0x00007f17a5560bf9 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x94bbf9)
#12 0x00007f17a5182e55 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x56de55)
#13 0x00007f17a5560bca (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x94bbca)
#14 0x00007f17a5183c68 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x56ec68)
#15 0x00007f17a5182a62 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x56da62)
#16 0x00007f17a5155a4b (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x540a4b)
#17 0x00007f17a51558ea (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x5408ea)
#18 0x00007f17a503f279 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x42a279)
#19 0x00007f17a5041387 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x42c387)
#20 0x00007f17a51f7852 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x5e2852)
#21 0x00007f17a55e4274 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x9cf274)
#22 0x00007f17a55e442e (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x9cf42e)
#23 0x00007f17a52e5636 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x6d0636)
#24 0x00007f17a52e4553 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x6cf553)
#25 0x00007f17a52e435a (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x6cf35a)
#26 0x00007f17a4ff036f (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x3db36f)
#27 0x00007f17a4ff1542 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x3dc542)
#28 0x00007f17a5006f3e (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x3f1f3e)
#29 0x00007f17a51e4368 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x5cf368)
#30 0x00007f17a5218575 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x603575)
#31 0x00007f17a5223fe8 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x60efe8)
#32 0x00007f17a51b47de (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x59f7de)
#33 0x00007f17a51aea8d (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x599a8d)
#34 0x00007f17a51b582e (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x5a082e)
#35 0x00007f17a51bf790 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x5aa790)
#36 0x00007f17a50dfd04 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblldb-17.so.1+0x4cad04)
#37 0x00007f17994abac3 start_thread ./nptl/pthread_create.c:442:8
#38 0x00007f179953d850 ./misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:83:0
LLDB diagnostics will be written to /tmp/diagnostics-8926df
Please include the directory content when filing a bug report
[1]    1201556 floating point exception  lldb-17```

Question:
What could be causing LLDB-17 to crash with a floating point exception when debugging this specific project? How can I further diagnose and resolve this issue? I have also tried lldb-18.

